# Memory increase during navigation, but heap looks fine?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I'm currently trying to optimize the memory usage of my application and I notice a behavior that looks strange to me, so I was wondering whether or not this was normal.

I'm performing a series of navigations between different instances of the same page, I checked and the garbage collector seems to be working fine, as after every navigation the page instances are destroyed correctly, as well as the ViewModel instances and the model instances in each ViewModel.

But, after every navigation I see a constant *increase in memory usage* (tested both in Debug and Release mode). Here's a snapshot:

[image: Memory usage snapshot]

As you can see in the memory chart on the right, the memory usage is increasing, the maximum value was around **108MB** when I started the app, and in the screen it reached **127MB**. I mean that's fine, the app runs ok, but I'm not sure whether or not this is normal.
The heap size seems to be *less than **2MB***, so where do these **~20MB** of used memory come from?

The biggest objects in the heap all seem to be system objects (other than that `UserHamburgerButtonViewModel` that contains the avatar image of the current user, that's the reason for its size), but anyways the total size of the objects in the heap is way lower than those 20MB of memory.

If I keep navigating I can see that the app will take *more or less **1MB*** for each navigation, the heap size stays the same but the total amount of private memory keeps increasing, so I don't know what's going on here.

**EDIT**: In response to @Michał Komorowski here is another screenshot with the GC calls, the problem is still there:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In a UWP app, not all memory is managed by the garbage collector. Your managed heap doesn't grow, but the total memory does. That implies that the growth happens in unmanaged memory, e.g. Windows Runtime objects. Those are reference counted, and should be reclaimed. But that memory is not compacted. What you are seeing may be the result of unmanaged memory fragmentation. Or it could be a genuine memory leak.

Comment: @Sergio0694 it looks fine. CLR could have increased the heap size, also did you try using `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`? You can also add `Debug` to output `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)`.
Anyway, it looks ok. WCF service, for example, that starts at ~120MB can rise to somewhere around 300MB and then stay at this mark going slightly up or down forever.

Answer (score 0):

In the picture, included by you, I don't see any garbage collections - they are indicated by yellow pointers. In other words even if there are unused objects in the memory they haven't been collected (freed) yet and it is why the memory usage increases. Garbage collection is generally a slow operation and shouldn't be performed too often. Under normal conditions it is only run when it is needed.

Try to run your application for a longer amount of time e.g. several minutes. At some point you should observe a garbage collection and the usage of the memory will decrease.

If you don't want to wait several minutes you can do one more exercise i.e. to programaticaly force GC by calling [GC.Collect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) method. **However, as the rule of thumb, never use *GC.Collect()* in production.** If you need to do that, it means that something is wrong with your code.

**UPDATE 1**

In *Diagnostic Tools* window you have *Memory Usage* tab. There you have *Take Snapshot* button. Click it before a navigation and after a navigation. You should see something like that:

[image]

In this example you can see that 4000 additional objects were created in the meantime. If you click a link you will see a new window showing objects of which types have been actually created.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I'll also edit my question to add this, but I have already tried to call both GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() a few times, even after every navigation, but it doesn't change anything, the reserved memory keeps increasing after every navigation

Comment: As for your EDIT, I've already tried using that snapshot feature, the heap always have around 14-15k items (they seem to be runtime objects, not items from my own code) and the size around 1-1.7MB, so that can't be it.. I mean the heap does look fine, I have no idea where the increased memory is coming from